# Use Spark coalesce without decreasing earlier operations parallelism

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql-repartition

Let’s say you had a parallelism of 1000, but you only wanted to write 10 files at the end:

```
load().map(…).filter(…).coalesce(10).save()
```

However, Spark’s will effectively push down the coalesce operation to as early a point as possible, so this will execute as:

```
load().coalesce(10).map(…).filter(…).save()
```

I know I can use an action (between the transformations and the coalesce) to workaround this behavior but I don't want to perform an action.

The question is how to write fewer files without changing the parallelism (except for the file writing of course)?

BTW, I know I can use `repartition` but I prefer something without shuffling which is faster like `coalesce`.